# What is the following list of behind the scenes inside the range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am studying C++ and I saw a range-based `for` loop like this:

```
for (int i : {1,2,3,4,5})
    std::cout << i << ' ';
```

What is the temporary `{1,2,3,4,5}` in the for loop behind the scenes?

Comment: try `{true, false}` for kicks.

Comment: @user1095108 It's fine, But i think It is simple and understandable to everyone .

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The object here is an instance of [`std::initializer_list<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). From the reference (emphasis mine):

> A std::initializer_list object is automatically constructed when:
>
> a braced-init-list is used to list-initialize an object, where the corresponding constructor accepts an std::initializer_list parameter
>
> a braced-init-list is used as the right operand of assignment or as a function call argument, and the corresponding assignment operator/function accepts an std::initializer_list parameter
>
> a braced-init-list is bound to auto, including **in a ranged for loop**

Comment: The braced initializer list is not an object, but I guess pretending that it is is fine in this case.

Answer (score 18):

> What is the temporary {1,2,3,4,5} in the for loop behind the scenes?

a [`std::initializer_list<int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Comment: Could have added some text from that link.